# Why should I use "a" before "a bit better", "a littlge highter" "a bit harsh"?

Tags: grammar, definite-article, indefinite-article

in this phrase(I am not sure this is a phrase)but

Why should I use "**a**" before

"**a** bit better", "**a** little higher" and "**a** bit harsh"?

I know this is an article( a or the) and I know why I need to use a or the before such as an apple, the school, a store but I do not know why I need to use a before these phrases..
In my opinion, it still makes sense to me  even though I say
"Sundays were bit better" something like that(even grammarly says I need to use "**a**", but I do not know why..

Can someone explain to me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples "**a bit**" means **somewhat; to some extent**. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bit)]
Although it's short, it is a *set phrase*: you would need to ask an etymologist why it starts with "a".

"**a little**" - in your examples - means "slightly". You need "a" because without it the meaning changes completely.

For example. You ask your partner to move a bookshelf a few inches higher. When s/he has finished you go and look at it.

If it is **a little higher** than it was you may be pleased.
If it is **little higher** than it was you may be disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

**A bit** and **a little** need the article because they are nouns meaning **a small amount**. If something is a bit better it is better by a small amount. **Slightly, much** and other adverbs you might use do not need an article.